# shinydashboard: switch tab if sidebar item expands

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am working on a shiny dashboard which has a sidebar with multiple menu items. One of the items is expandable. I want to switch tabs if a menu item is clicked. This works perfectly for menu items which are not expandable, but with the expandable one I have some troubles.

A workaround could be to place an actionlink inside the expandle menu and observe it. But what I want to do instead, is to switch the tab as soon as the collapsed menu is expanded. I tried to use `input$sidebarItemExpand` and `shinydashboard::updateTabItem`, but somehow nothing happens ... if somebody has an idea what went wrong, please let me know

```
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#   UI ====
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

header <- shinydashboard::dashboardHeader()

sidebar <- shinydashboard::dashboardSidebar(
    shinydashboard::sidebarMenu(
        id="tabs",
        shinydashboard::menuItem(
            text="menu_expand",
            tabName="tab1",
            shiny::selectInput(
                inputId="sel_123",
                label="123",
                choices=c("A","B","C"),
                selected="A")),
        shinydashboard::menuItem(
            text="menu_item_normal1",
            tabName="tab2"),
        shinydashboard::menuItem(
            text="menu_item_normal2",
            tabName="tab3")))

body <- shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
    shinydashboard::tabItems(
        shinydashboard::tabItem(
            tabName = "tab1",
            shiny::h3("Tab 1")
        ),
        shinydashboard::tabItem(
            tabName = "tab2",
            shiny::h3("Tab 2")
        ),
        shinydashboard::tabItem(
            tabName = "tab3",
            shiny::h3("Tab 3"))))

ui <- shinydashboard::dashboardPage(header,sidebar,body)

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#   SERVER ====
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

server <- function(input,output,session){
    shiny::observeEvent(input$sidebarItemExpanded, {
        print(input$sidebarItemExpanded)
        if(input$sidebarItemExpanded == "menu_expand"){
            print("expanded")
            shinydashboard::updateTabItems(
                session=session,"tabs","tab1"
            )
        }
    })
}

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#   LAUNCH APP ====
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

shiny::shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place `menutitem` with `tabName` `tab1` one level inside the expand-menu as you could have multiple tabs and submenuitems in there too.  Try this code.

```
sidebar <- shinydashboard::dashboardSidebar(
  shinydashboard::sidebarMenu(
    id="tabs",
    shinydashboard::menuItem(text="menu_expand", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"),
                              menuItem("menu_expanded", tabName = "tab1", icon = icon("bar-chart-o")),
      # text="menu_expand",
      # tabName="tab1",
      shiny::selectInput(
        inputId="sel_123",
        label="123",
        choices=c("A","B","C"),
        selected="A")),
    shinydashboard::menuItem(
      text="menu_item_normal1",
      tabName="tab2"),
    shinydashboard::menuItem(
      text="menu_item_normal2",
      tabName="tab3")))
```

Comment: works like a charm. for aesthetic reasons I set text and icon inside the main menu to blank, but apart from that, your solution is exactely what I was looking for. (and I learned to accept, that the shiny logic sometimes confueses me :D)

Comment: Hi! @sambold could you please share how to set text and icon to blank? I am struggling with a similar issue